# mssql_query is not working: error message delivered is "Warning: mssql_query(): 7 is not a valid MS SQL-Link resource"

Tags: php, sql-server, transactions, commit

I have a problem while querying a SQL server DB from a PHP procedure.
My code is :

```
$commit = FALSE;
            $rs = mssql_query("BEGIN TRANSACTION");
            if($rs) {
                // funzione salvataggio in PrenotazioniFerservizi_Variazioni            
                InsertDisdetta($id_albergo, $POA, $Treno, $Ora_treno, $elenco_giorni_Ok, $subject, $data_email);
                $commit = TRUE;
            }else{
                $msg = "Errore nella BEGIN TRAN<br>Riga ".__LINE__."<br>".mssql_get_last_message();
                InviaMailErrore("Errore nella query", $msg);
                // chiudo la connessione al dbd se ancora aperta
                @mssql_close($con);
                die();
            }
            if($commit) {
                $rs = mssql_query("COMMIT TRAN");               
                if (!$rs){
                    $msg = "Errore nella COMMIT TRANSACTION<br>Riga ".__LINE__."<br>".mssql_get_last_message();
                    InviaMailErrore("Errore nella query", $msg);
                    // chiudo la connessione al dbd se ancora aperta
                    @mssql_close($con);
                    die();
                }
            }
```

It returns me following error message:

"Warning: mssql_query(): 7 is not a valid MS SQL-Link resource" and it seems to be related specifically to instruction:

Do you have a clue ?
Is very important please.
Thks a lot in advance.
D.

Comment: and changing COMMIT TRAN by COMMIT TRANSACTION ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user2111997 Are you sure you are connected to a database, I do not see a connect code in your code, and the error also indicates that the link is not valid (thus maybe not connected).

Comment: Yes, I opened it in some other line that I did not show in the post  :-(

Comment: Woooow...I have just detected there was a close connection instruction in the middle. Thank you so much for making me think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best alternative, but I solved the error closing the connection (mssql_close) and so everything still works. Previously I worked at a time does not work for, testing and removing the closure of the connection was that I could run my connection. More research is more ...